# Request object has no 'user'

Tags: python, django

I have an Django app that works completely fine in localhost but when I try to use it in prod(hosted on DO), I get weird error every time the app tries to `get_user`. Example: When I browse to the admin interface, this is what I see: [image]

I cannot figure out the reason at all! This is very confusing. Any pointers in this regard is appreciated.

Edit: Traceback for clarification: http://dpaste.com/3HBPXJC

Edit 2: Every request coming through or made by domainname.com shows this error and from www.domainname.com is fine! I'm pretty new to this and I'm sure I'm making a stupid mistake. Any hints here?

Comment: Please post a traceback.

Comment: @ChristopherSchäpers I have shared the link for traceback. Can you please check it.

Comment: You're going to need to say what package you're using here. It's not django-social-auth, since that has no module backends/base. What is it?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am using Python-Social-Auth which works completely fine on localhost. Also, I am getting this error when I try to login even to admin interface.

Comment: just thought I'd let you know the site address is viewable in the traceback, I thought you'd want to censor it.

Comment: @DorianDore Thanks, will scratch it out.

Comment: Can you post what backends are you using in social auth?

Comment: @GwynBleidD it's Python-Social-Auth

Comment: closed issue, but same error https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/issues/68

Answer (score 1):

Well, I will try to help you to find the solution. According with this: http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/django.html#register-the-application, you should register the application you will use. I suggest you use the default one for this case:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'social.apps.django_app.default',
    ...
)
```

And I can't see that [here](http://dpaste.com/3HBPXJC). It is just one thing that comes to my head while taking a look to your issue, but it would be useful if you go through all the steps on the integration with `Django` [doc](http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/django.html).

I hope that can help you with that. Thanks.